# Problem with sending custom variable Value in tradingview alert message

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to send Custom variable value using plot function inside pine-script.

```
plot(0.42, title="SL")
alertcondition(condition=b_long , title='L', message='msg_{{plot("SL"}}_{{close}}')
```

This works only when i dont have long pine-script, more than ~400 lines of code.

Problem is that tradeview  does not replace {{plot("SL")}} with value that is circulated inside pine-script.
and the message i got is **msg_{{plot("SL"}}_8873.34** instead of  **msg_0.42_8873.34**
I have  encounters strange problem that makes problem only when i have pinescript is long

Do you have similar problem?
Any ideas how to solve it?
Posting Support Ticketing on tradeview  is currently impossible.

Comment: Finally after a lot of experimenting i have figured, that Tradingview exposes only first 19 plot variables to alarms. So  the variables after {{plot_19}} or{{plot("mva200")}} are not evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue and tested all kinds of stuff. In the end I rebuild a simple new study with sending the most simple custom variable to an alert and it worked (magically). After that I added the code from the study that didn't work and for some reason it now works. This feels like a bug, because there is literally no difference between the 2 study's. Hope this works for you as well!

Edit: The only difference is now that all the indicators are now plotted below the graph. Not sure that makes a difference.

Comment: Still an issue in 2024. I have to set overplay=false, add the indicator to the chart, then create an alert, and wait for it to be triggered. After that, set overplay back to true, and it starts to work.